# How to return a input value from a extended child widget to the parent widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have problems understanding how to pass input information from a extended child widget back to its parent widget. I tried to create a setter in the parent widget but i can not call it through the "ParentWidget.of(context).setterName".

What is the best way to pass the user input information from a child widget back to a parent?

Thanks for your help

```
class SignInMobilePortrait extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignInMobilePortraitState createState() => _SignInMobilePortraitState();
}

class _SignInMobilePortraitState extends State<SignInMobilePortrait> {

  //text field state
  String _email = '';

  set email(String value) => setState(() => _email = value);

  ...

  LoginCredentials(),

  ...

}

class LoginCredentials extends StatelessWidget {

  LoginCredentials({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return Container(

     ...

                onChanged: (value) {
                 //CHANGE EMAIL VALUE HERE;
                },
     ...
}
```

Comment: Can you add what you've tried?

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi I thought about passing a function which will set the email and that should work but I dont understand why I cant call the setter

Comment: I though its there to set the values of some variables

Comment: So you want to return a particular value from a TextField in the LoginCredentials....to the SignInMobilePortrait?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A correct way to do this is to pass `TextEditingController` from `SignInMobilePortrait` down to `LoginCredentials`:

```dart
class _SignInMobilePortraitState extends State<SignInMobilePortrait> {

  final _emailController = TextEditingController();

  LoginCredentials(_emailController),

  ...
  // Access _emailController.text somewhere

}


class LoginCredentials extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  LoginCredentials({
    Key key,
    @required this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return TextField(
     ...
     controller: controller,
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much thats exactly what I was looking for. My current solution passed a function to the child widget which just doesnt look very nice